# C++11 (std=c++0x) support on Vortex86DX i486 hardware and gcc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, embedded-linux

I´m building a project that I need to run in a Vortex86DX i486 embedded system. It comes with a so called D&P XLinux ([http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/os-xlinux/)](http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/os-xlinux/).

There I need support for C++11 (std=c++0x), where the compiler that comes with the board does not support - gcc version 3.2.3.

I was checking the GCC page to check how shall I upgrade my current compiler and I have my doubts about how to upgrade the compiler and choose the correct version:

a) Which is the first GCC version that supported C++11 ? 
b) Does that version has support for i486 ? Can I built it for my Vortex hardware ?
c) Is there a better approach to support C++11 on this hardaware ?

In fact, my other alternative is to change the code *not* to use C++11. That will be a huge effort and some libraries (like cryptopp) may make this very problematic.

Thanks for hints and help.

Comment: what is the latest gcc version you can upgrade to on your board ? What are the potential problems if you update with this version ?

Comment: In fact I don´t know. This is the version available and it does not seem to have a newer compiler. My idea is to build the gcc compiler locally in the board. I´m using XLinux from `http://www.dmp.com.tw/tech/os-xlinux/`

Comment: Consider http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gcc.html, which details the procedure independent of which version of Linux one is using. It discusses the care to be taken regarding the standard library on your version of linux (i.e. not XLinux specifically, but whatever version of Linux one may have). It's aimed, it SEEMS, to those on unusual flavors lacking 'mainstream' support for upgrading GCC.

Comment: Further, you have asked for a large range of potential answers. C++0x and C++11 support have come incrementally in GCC, where, say, 4.4 is possibly sufficient for your code, but perhaps you require ranged based for, which started around 4.6 (see https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html and similar for a chart). It seems deprecation of i386 began around 4.8, and I don't yet find info on i486, but by 4.8 or 4.9, which has i486 support, there is significant C++11 coverage